# JavaFX How to deploy an application and make my resource available in code?

Tags: java, javafx, deployment

I have written an JavaFX application to study German language with a Flashcard like program. It turned out my classmate also want this but I don't know how to deploy it.

I have a sqlite database which store some german words and I need read/write access. I have tried hardcode the path but it obviously is not good. I have tried to load the sqlite file by the following line and deploy it as a runnable jar but I couldn't write on it.

```
"jdbc:sqlite::resource:Vokabeln.sqlite"
```

Assume that I don't want to make remote web application, how should I make this file available to my code, and is platform independent? Should I make a installer program so that I ask the user what is the path? I also don't know how to write an installer application. I googled and didn't find anything like that.

Comment: I'm afraid this is going to be far too broad of a question for StackOverflow. However, many IDEs provide a way to create an executable JAR file for your application. Once that's done, you'll need to distribute the database file with the JAR and make sure it's accessible by your code.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to distribute your application with the database as a file outside of the Jar because otherwise you won't be able to have write access to it.

If the database file is on the same directory/folder as the Jar file, you should be able to connect to it with a JDBC URL like the following: `jdbc:sqlite:sample.db`

Distributing your application as a Zip file is fine, but if you can't expect end users to have Java installed and so, there are programs to create installers, even cross-platform, such as [IzPack](http://izpack.org/) and [Install4J](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/install4j/overview.html)

Comment: Thank you. I would try that.